# PowerPivot Service Application Database is offline

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-server, powerpivot

I recently used an assessment tool which gave me the error in the title.

Description:

> PowerPivot Service Application database is offline eventhough the
>   PowerPivot Service Application & proxy are online.

Is it safe to assume that if the database offline the service not functional therefore there will be no implications if I disable it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you used the RAP tool. We had the exact same error reported as critical. Interesting thing is, we are on the standard edition of SharePoint so there is no way to have PowerPivot in that farm.

Vendor told us, ignore this one as they have to update the use case / filters on tool side. They marked it as resolved.

Comment: Awesome to read that. I am indeed using the RAP tool. And after posting this question I looked everywhere for a sight of PowerPivot and we don't even have it too... Thank you!

Comment: we ran against 2016 as well and same error popup...interesting thing is, RAP marked it critical.

Comment: Weird. There are a lot of false positives though. And I am using a new version of the tool, updated last week.